# RxJS: Get multiple response

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming

I have 'nested' requests, team creation and team avatar uploading, wherein second depends on first and should be sent only if avatar is not null (I've already done this using filter operator). What I need now is to get access to both responses in subscribe method.

```
this.team.createTeam(teamRequest)
    .pipe(
        filter(() => avatar),
        flatMap(next => this.team.uploadLogo(avatar, next.body.uuid)
    ).subscribe(responses => {
        // so, I want response from both createTeam and uploadLogo in responses
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pipe in a `map` operator to the inner request and send both the responses. Try the following

```js
this.team.createTeam(teamRequest)
  .pipe(
    filter(() => avatar),
    flatMap(next => 
      this.team.uploadLogo(avatar, next.body.uuid).pipe(
        map(res => ({ avatar: res, team: next }))
      )
    )
  ).subscribe(responses => {
      // responses.avatar: response from `this.team.uploadLogo(avatar, next.body.uuid)` 
      // responses.team: response from `this.team.createTeam(teamRequest)` 
  });
```

I've returned an object for illustration. You could return it in any form as per your requirement. Eg. as an array `map(res => [ next, res ]))`.

#### Update: `iif` function instead of `filter` operator

If you still want to subscribe to the source observable when the `filter` condition fails, the quickest way I could think of is to forgo the `filter` operator and use [`iif`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/iif) function instead. Try the following

```js
const upload = (avatar, team): Observable<any> => {
  return this.team.uploadLogo(avatar, next.body.uuid).pipe(
    map(res => ({ avatar: avatar, team: team }))
  );
};

iif(() =>
  !!avatar,
  this.team.createTeam(teamRequest).pipe(flatMap(next => upload(avatar, next.body.uuid))),
  this.team.createTeam(teamRequest)
).subscribe(
  responses => {
    // if `avatar` is null
    // responses: response from `this.team.createTeam(teamRequest)`
    // or
    // if `avatar` is non-null
    // responses.avatar: response from `this.team.uploadLogo(avatar, next.body.uuid)` 
    // responses.team: response from `this.team.createTeam(teamRequest)` 
  }
);
```

#### Update: check `avatar` inside the `flatMap`

As suggested by @bryan60, here is a more cleaner code that uses neither `filter` nor `iif`. But rather checks `avatar` inside the `flatMap` and returns `of(next)` if it's null.

```js
this.team.createTeam(teamRequest).pipe(
  flatMap(next => {
    if (!!avatar) {
      return this.team.uploadLogo(avatar, next.body.uuid).pipe(
        map(res => ({ avatar: res, team: next }))
      );
    }
    return of(next);
  })
).subscribe(responses => {
    // if `avatar` is null
    // responses: response from `this.team.createTeam(teamRequest)`
    // or
    // if `avatar` is non-null
    // responses.avatar: response from `this.team.uploadLogo(avatar, next.body.uuid)` 
    // responses.team: response from `this.team.createTeam(teamRequest)` 
});
```

Comment: The alias `flatMap` is deprecated, better use `mergeMap`.

Comment: Btw if avatar is null and filter fails, I still need to get response from createTeam. How can I do that??

Comment: @fridoo: Could you please say where the deprecation is mentioned? I couldn't find it in https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/deprecations.

Comment: @MichaelD, so can you help me with my issue, i mentioned above?

Comment: @ArthCode: The quickest way I could think of is to use `iif` function instead of the `filter` operator. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Yep, I've been also thinking through this way. Thank you one more time.

Comment: you could just check inside of the `flatMap` operator and return `of({team:next})` or similar if no `avatar` ... code is slightly cleaner

Comment: @bryan60: But the source response wouldn't be emitted to the `flatMap` if the `filter` condition fails?

Comment: remove the filter condition.

Comment: @bryan60: Yes that's better. I've updated the answer. Thanks.

Comment: `flatMap` deprecation is mentioned in the code https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/193e51904faa940a8ac14df6e91bbf1b4d148a42/src/internal/operators/mergeMap.ts#L177 my local vs code also displays that message.

Comment: So, guys, thank you all very very much. You've developed my rxjs understanding a lot. Thank you also for 3 different ways to solve my issue. Good luck!